# Array out of bounds in ViewPager

Tags: android, arrays, android-viewpager

I am getting an array out of bounds exception with in the `ViewPager` class but I am un sure why.

It seems to occur when swiping the view pager quickly and it looks like the internal array that holds the items is empty since it is trying to grab index 0.

Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.performDrag(ViewPager.java:2343)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2262)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8471)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2399)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2092)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2106)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8666)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4123)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3989)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3737)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3597)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3563)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3571)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3544)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5807)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5781)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5752)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5897)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.ja
```

Here is code the code the sets up the view page and setting the adapter. In this case we are following the isTablet path.

```
private void initializePaging() {

    if (resources.getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        menuGridSize = 3;
    }
    else {
        menuGridSize = 4;
    }

    if (mMenus != null) {
        if (Utility.isTabletDevice(getActivity())) {
            int count = mMenus.size() / menuGridSize;
            int extras = mMenus.size() % menuGridSize;

            int activatedIndicator = 0;
            if (pageIndicators != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < pageIndicators.size(); i++) {
                    if (pageIndicators.get(i).isActivated()) {
                        activatedIndicator = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            pageIndicatorLayout.removeAllViews();
            pageIndicators = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                ImageView temp = new ImageView(context);
                temp.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                temp.setImageDrawable(mTheme.pageIndicatorSelector(context));
                pageIndicatorLayout.addView(temp);
                pageIndicators.add(temp);
            }

            if (extras != 0) {
                ImageView temp = new ImageView(context);
                temp.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                temp.setImageDrawable(mTheme.pageIndicatorSelector(context));
                pageIndicatorLayout.addView(temp);
                pageIndicators.add(temp);
            }
            pageIndicators.get(activatedIndicator).setActivated(true);

            if (pageIndicators.size() <= 1) {
                pageIndicatorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (adapter == null) {
                adapter = new MainMenuPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), mMenus, menuGridSize, changeFragmentListener);
            }
            else {
                adapter.setGridSize(menuGridSize);
            }

            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

                }

                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

                }

                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < pageIndicators.size(); i++) {
                        if (i == arg0) {
                            pageIndicators.get(i).setActivated(true);
                        }
                        else {
                            pageIndicators.get(i).setActivated(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            menuList.setAdapter(new MainMenuAdapter(getActivity(), mMenus));
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            menuList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        view.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Here is the code for adapter

```
public class MainMenuPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public static final String TAG = "MainMenuPagerAdapter";

private List<GenericMenu> menus = new ArrayList<>();
private int gridSize;
private ChangeFragmentListener changeFragmentListener;

public MainMenuPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<GenericMenu> menus, int gridSize, final ChangeFragmentListener changeFragmentListener) {

    super(fragmentManager);
    this.menus = menus;
    this.gridSize = gridSize;
    this.changeFragmentListener = changeFragmentListener;
}

public void setGridSize(int gridSize) {

    this.gridSize = gridSize;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    int subListStart = position * gridSize;
    int subListEnd = position * gridSize + gridSize;

    if (subListEnd >= menus.size()) {
        subListEnd = menus.size();
    }

    // find the menus for this page
    ArrayList<GenericMenu> subList = new ArrayList<GenericMenu>();
    subList.addAll(menus.subList(subListStart, subListEnd));

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("menus", subList);
    bundle.putInt("columns", gridSize);
    MainMenuPageFragment fragment = new MainMenuPageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragment.setChangeFragmentListener(new ChangeFragmentListener() {

        public void changeFragment(BaseIceFragment fragment, String titleText, String image, float size) {

            if (changeFragmentListener != null) {
                changeFragmentListener.changeFragment(fragment, titleText, image, size);
            }
        }
    });

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    int count = menus.size() / gridSize;
    count += menus.size() % gridSize > 0 ? 1 : 0;

    return count;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {

    // Do nothing
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share your source code?

Comment: Do you want the ViewPager code

Comment: That and your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is probably caused by the source file. In ViewPager setAdaper() mItems is set to null. When you drag ViewPager and when the setAdapter is called then this issue occurs. You can see the performDrag() method mItems.get(0) don't add size check.

SOLUTION: Use notifyDataChanged to refresh data instead of setAdapter:

```
if(mAdapter == null){
    mAdapter = new CarInfoViewPagerAdapter(views);
} else {
    mAdapter.setViews(views);
}
if(mViewPager.getAdapter() == null){
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
} else {
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

- Since you didn't provide code, I just made up the names - mItems, mAdapter and mViewPager, but I'm sure you will be able to relate. Hope this helps.